# Where to process GDPR questions

Tags: discussion, tags

The General Data Protection Regulation ([gdpr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gdpr)) has an impact on every aspect of every information processing organization that operates in Europe or on Europeans.  The scope of the GDPR touches the organisation at every level, management, paper and computer systems, and code.  Where is the proper forum for questions on this topic?

Background: When I asked a GDPR question (that was not a code question) in SO I got punished, and the question was suspended. At the same time, more or less, a  code question in SO actually required an answer that was a summary of the GDPR's requirements in general, i.e. not code. I provided an answer and it was well received.

So it's a bit of a mess.

Comment: Programming questions can be here but the question you asked that got closed appears to be a legal question. A coding question might be well served by an answer without code but you can't ask a non-programming question here. You might try the Law SE but I'd ask on their Meta first (I don't know whether either of the financial SEs would work.)

Comment: The GDPR by itself is not a programming issue I think?

Comment: *seems to be getting a free pass* - It really shouldn't be. If it is it's because it's a relatively new, low traffic tag and not getting attention from users who know better. It's usage guidance is totally wrong though: people should NOT be asking policy questions here.

Comment: Guys, tell me something I didn't know.  For example, where should wide ranging systems questions (with potentially massive code impact) be asked?  I understand the purity thing.  I get it, but now I want results.

Comment: If you don't want to try Law SE the only other thing I can think of is creating a site for these types of questions on [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/) but that's a long process. But you also might get better suggestions on where to ask over on the [Uber Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) since that site has users from all over the network.

Comment: Most questions that exist in the [tag:gdpr] are legal compliance questions or otherwise entirely unrelated to programming. I haven't looked at each of them but most questions I have seen are off-topic for the site; I'm not sure the tag is on-topic at all.

Comment: Heck, the very first question to use the tag was literally just "how many pages are there in the GDPR document".

Comment: @TylerH pic or never happened!

Comment: @Braiam Sorry, it was how many articles (sections), not how many pages: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43654972/gdpr-articles-how-many The question is not deleted or even closed. And looking at it now, the tag was added two weeks ago by someone whose edit was *approved* by two other users... yikes.

Comment: ..and most of the questions are tangential to GDPR anyway. Just because you ask a programming question about a GDPR button...doesn't require the GDPR *tag*...sigh. Whole thing could use a cleanup.

Comment: FWIW, nearly all (1 remains a close-vote short) [tag:gdpr] questions on Stack Overflow have been closed for various applicable reasons. If there is not already a GDPR-focused Area 51 site, perhaps one should be suggested. While compliance questions are likely on-topic at Law.SE (though legal advice questions would not be), I imagine GDPR compliance to be a sufficiently hot topic to sustain its own beta site, at least for a while...

Comment: There's a related question on Software Engineering Meta about whether they'd be willing to accept any of these questions [here](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8723/does-software-engineering-se-accept-gdpr-and-other-legal-compliance-type-questio). If they agree, I suspect that they'd want to focus on "system-level" questions (i.e. requirements writing, architecture, etc.)

Comment: @TylerH I can't imagine there being enough to discuss about GDPR to sustain its own site long-term. After all, we only got approximately 45 questions here over the course of a few months, which really isn't enough to justify a completely new site.

Comment: @EJoshuaS To be fair the law hasn't gone into effect yet. Once thousands of companies start getting 10% of their profits fined suddenly (or whatever the rate is) I imagine there will be a lot more scrambling to comply. But it's hard for me to say how many questions it will generate; I'm from the United States.

Comment: @TylerH I'm from the U.S. as well but I work for a German-based company - it's definitely a major topic here. I think that the fine is up to 5% of revenue if I'm not mistaken, which seems pretty draconian to me, but they didn't consult me about the law.

Comment: @EJoshuaS -- The maximum fine is up to 4% of gross world-wide revenue.

Answer (score 11):

You asked:

> Where is the proper forum for questions on this topic?

You kind of answered it yourself by saying:

> The scope of the GDPR touches the organisation at every level,
>   management, paper and computer systems, and code.

So, the proper forum will depend on the **scope** of the question you're asking.

For example, if your question about GDPR involves only the legal aspect you might refer to [Law.SE](https://law.stackexchange.com/). If the question refer to political impacts then you should head to [Politics.SE](https://politics.stackexchange.com/). If there's code involved, you should head to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/). If it has something to do with how GDPR affecting your workplace, you might want to try [The Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Note, that most of the time, the behavior of the code can be mostly abstracted from the specific use-case that it's meant to fulfill. If I need to sum two numbers in python, it doesn't matter if I'm building a calculator, a cart handler or a high precision missile guiding system, so most of the time even the tag is irrelevant.

Comment: I have an outstanding question on [Software Engineering SE Meta](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8723/does-software-engineering-se-accept-gdpr-and-other-legal-compliance-type-questio) about whether they'd be willing to accept some of these questions if they're focused on architecture and/or requirements-writing.

Comment: Is there a place in SO for real cries for help from people who do not know quite what they are asking and are seriously in need of advice?  Maybe this is a uber-meta question. Finally, @Tyl, the USA will be getting its own GDPR soon if Zuckerberg has any say in it.  Then interest will rocket.

Comment: @Aethelbald If anyone will be advocating for more privacy laws it *won't* be Mark Zuckerberg. His company actively lobbies *against* laws and efforts to increase privacy restrictions, because such laws mean less money for Facebook.

Comment: @TylerH, https://www.theverge.com/2018/4/11/17224492/zuckerberg-facebook-congress-gdpr-data-protection

Comment: @Aethelbald That's Facebook complying with GDPR, not all him advocating for a US-based GDPR.