# Burninate [gdpr]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

Related: [Where to process GDPR questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/365942/where-to-process-gdpr-questions)

[gdpr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gdpr)

Normally I'm suggesting we take action against a tag, but this tag is practically already burninated because nobody has managed to ask an on-topic question. I'm more posting this so we have official Meta discussion about keeping the tag. The root problem here is that people keep asking questions that are generally boiling down to

> How do I comply with the EU GDPR law?

[Here's a prime example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49985063/does-the-new-eu-gdpr-law-protect-you-against-an-obligation-to-use-cookies)

That's not a programming question, that's a legal one. In most cases, the ones asking good questions are just not for SO. So I am proposing that we simply remove this tag and tell future users that GDPR questions belong on [Law.SE](//law.stackexchange.com) to determine what they should do to be compliant with the law.

Comment: It's 22 questions, that's a few minutes of work if you wanted to do this.

Comment: @EthanField To remove the tag, sure, but there are still open off-topic questions from my quick look- A few extra hands would be useful to close those. Much easier while the tag is still on them, so they can be found easily. In addition, there might be a reason this tag is worth keeping, and this post gives people a chance to argue that point before the tag just vanishes.

Comment: @EthanField It's less than that. There's only 4 open right now, and all have close votes

Comment: While I think it's possible for a GDPR related question to be on-topic on this site, it would need to be specific enough for it not to need that tag in the first place. If someone needs to do X in order to be compliant then they can ask about X without needing the tag and if they don't know what X is then I don't see a good question coming out of that.

Comment: @ivarni That's kinda where I am. There might be an edge case here and there, but it's a terrible reason to have a tag that invites people to ask legal questions

Comment: Now, if we can just figure out how to burninate the actual GDPR...

Comment: *..this tag is practically already burninated..* 

I can't find the chat message now but TylerH was kind enough to go through all of the GDPR questions when I asked about it. I thought about doing a burninate request myself but then thought the edit to the tag info might have been enough. Clearly I was wrong.

Comment: Tag is now empty.  Does it need blacklisting or should we just let it die naturally?

Comment: @Kevin We let it die for now. If it returns, we request a blacklist

Comment: @Shog9 Yes, please - can you arrange that? Incidentally, the EU really should've posted on Meta before making the policy change so that I could downvote :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Animuson cleaned the tag out for the most part (a few others tossed 20k deletes) and so the tag is burninated.