# Blacklist [gdpr]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, blocklist-request

The [gdpr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gdpr) tag was [burninated](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366486/burninate-gdpr) on April 24<sup>th</sup>. On April 26<sup>th</sup> the tag was re-created:

> Questions related to EU General Data Protection Regulation (GDPR)

Not as bad as the first one, which explicitly claimed that legal questions were on topic, but it certainly implies that questions about the regulation itself are OK and there are already off-topic questions on the tag.

As we get closer to the date GDPR becomes enforceable, the number of questions related to GDPR is likely to increase. The tag should be blacklisted to prevent users from recreating it with usage guidance encouraging off-topic questions.

Comment: I'm not opposed to it, but I'd like to give people a link to a canonical resource that's likely to be more helpful than what they've found in the JIT help that shows when they try to use the tag - any suggestions on what we could link to?

Comment: @TimPost We could link to http://law.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: @TylerH They also have a [gdpr](https://law.stackexchange.com/tags/gdpr/info) tag but if we're encouraging people to post their instead, should we link to their [help](https://law.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) instead?

Comment: @BSMP Sure, I didn't mean that URL exactly, just the site in general.

Comment: can we make gdpr synonym to heachache-dossier?

Comment: Aside from one question about cookies (GDPR is meta there so retagged) the rest are now closed as off-topic

Comment: @TimPost EFF recommended https://www.twobirds.com/%7E/media/pdfs/gdpr-pdfs/bird--bird--guide-to-the-general-data-protection-regulation.pdf?la=en to [some](https://github.com/tootsuite/mastodon/issues/7280#issuecomment-385625490). Then maybe people need to first [read the basics](https://ec.europa.eu/info/law/law-topic/data-protection/reform/rules-business-and-organisations).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Ok, done.

[image: the gdpr tag is not allowed.]

Links to the GDPR tag on Law, and to the commission website found by Nemo.

Comment: I see we have succeed in making Europeans friendly again ...

Comment: @rene now we need to make the dutch friendly...