# Suggest merging [pci] and [pci-bus] tags, then do away with the former

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-disambiguation

Please rename [pci] > [pci-bus].

There are currently two primary meanings within the technology sphere for PCI:

1. The Peripheral Component Interconnect standard (usually referred to casually as "PCI bus")
2. The Payment Card Industry (which usually refers to its Data Security Standard)

The current [pci](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pci) tag is supposedly about the bus, but regularly gets questions posted to it about the PCI-DSS. I periodically go and edit those to have the correct tag ([pci-compliance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pci-compliance) or [pci-dss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pci-dss)).

Meanwhile, there is another tag named [pci-bus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pci-bus) which is defined in a very similar way to the current [pci](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pci) tag. (The [pci-bus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pci-bus) seems to have been intended to refer more specifically to the 1990s-era hardware standard. However, I can't find any question there explicitly dealing with the hardware standard; virtually all questions are about the PCI card interface -- that is, how to work with PCI cards generically from the software side.)

Currently people who do kernel/driver development assume that [pci](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pci) is for the bus. But evidently people who deal with the payment card industry assume [pci](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pci) is for their stuff.

I think it would make more sense to combine the tags [pci](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pci) and [pci-bus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pci-bus), moving all the current questions to the latter, then simply remove the [pci](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pci) tag altogether as it's ripe for misidentification. Not having a [pci](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pci) tag at all would, I hope, prod the average poster into considering the existing possibilities rather than blindly choosing the first one offered.

If this recommendation is accepted, I would suggest using the more generic description from the [pci](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pci) tag as the new description for the merged [pci-bus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pci-bus) tag.

There is also a [pci-e](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pci-e) (PCI-Express) tag, but questions there sometimes at least refer to aspects of it that are not shared with the original PCI or PCI-X bus implementations.

---

[pci](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pci) 334 Open Qs, 84 watchers

> Questions in this tag are only for questions related to the PCI Local Bus standard which is a computer bus for attaching hardware devices in a computer.

[pci-bus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pci-bus) 60 Open Qs, 9 watchers

> Peripheral Component Interconnect, PCI bus is the most used bus in computers during the late 1990's and early 2000's

[pci-compliance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pci-compliance) 241 Open Qs, 71 watchers

> The Payment Card Industry Data Security Standard (PCI DSS) is a set of requirements designed to ensure that ALL companies that process, store or transmit credit card information maintain a secure environment.

[pci-dss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pci-dss) 181 Open Qs, 64 watchers

> The Payment Card Industry Data Security Standard is a worldwide information security standard assembled by the Payment Card Industry Security Standards Council (PCI SSC).

[pci-e](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pci-e) 268 Open Qs, 79 watchers

> PCI-Express (PCIe) is a peer 2 peer interconnect which is based on PCI and PCI-X. Newest generation is gen 5.0. PCIe is maintained and developed by PCI-SIG.

**EDIT**: Summarizing:

I would like to combine `[pci]` into `[pci-bus]` then torch the former to remove the ambiguity it represents. (But retaining the slightly more general terminology used in the `[pci]` tag's description.

Comment: I want to do away with "pci" altogether as it is ambiguous. "pci-bus" on the other hand, is not. So merge seemed right. I may not be using proper terminology.

Comment: I'm wondering if [pci-compliance] isn't off-topic. Reminds me of the [GDPR discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/367027/blacklist-gdpr)

Comment: @Machavity - I don't think the two are similar enough for one to set a precedent over the other.  PCI compliance is a much more technical question, covering such things as use of appropriate technologies, software requirements, etc than GDPR compliance, which is more about business processes than anything else.

Comment: @Jules But many of the PCI Compliance questions are legal in nature. If you need some aspect of compliance (i.e TLS 1.2) that can be asked without needing a PCI Compliance tag.

Comment: It is not clean at the moment. Searching for `[pci] encryption` - which I happened to already know would find one that I *suspect* of being improperly categorized - actually shows several that are clearly about the payment card industry.

Comment: @pnuts I've made a pass through all the [tag:pci] questions and reclassified those which were not about the bus. I would now call it clean.

Comment: @pnuts I don't know the procedure, and would appreciate your assistance. As to which method, I have no opinion. Certainly feel free to transform this one, if that is appropriate.

Comment: Just got another question related to PCI compliance with the pci tag ;(

Comment: @pnuts The tag renaming question is gone?

Answer (score 3):

A tag ([pci-bus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pci-bus)) whose usage has grown to a mere 60 instances in 9 years is clearly serving little purpose. Judging by its Usage guide an explosion of use in the near future is not expected. For current purposes it is 'disposable'.

Tag [pci](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pci) has near-enough the same usage as the above but has an issue with being confused for a different "PCI". Applying [pci-bus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pci-bus) instead should help to reduce deconflating the two distinct meanings (attaching hardware devices v. payment card industry).

A synonym here is not desirable because of the ambiguity, so better to rename [pci](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pci) > [pci-bus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pci-bus). Because the quite large number of instances of [pci](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pci) this would be best actioned by a mod rather than by other users. But assurance from someone knowledgeable about [pci](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pci) that it is nowhere applied in the PCI-DSS meaning should come first.

Note mention that some merging of the Usage guides and tag wikis may be appropriate, perhaps with mention that [pci-bus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pci-bus) is *not* normally to be used in the context of the payment card industry.

There is a good case for a merge.