# This tag is in violation of [regulations]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

The [regulations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regulations) tag has the same basic problem [GDPR](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/367027/blacklist-gdpr) did: it's  encouraging off-topic questions. There's only 7 questions but at least 5 are off-topic questions about complying with law/policy.

Comment: A quick purge just leaves the GDPR one which will fall by the wayside as and when the question is Roomba'd

Comment: ..and then there were none! :)