# Burninate the [rocket] tag

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

Both [rocket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rocket) and [rkt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rkt) are for the same topic, the (now discontinued) Rocket container runtime.

"Rocket" is the name of a lot of different things – the [rkt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rkt) container runtime, the Rust web framework [rust-rocket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rust-rocket), Rocket Software products ([rocket-u2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rocket-u2)), [rocket.chat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rocket.chat), the [rocket-chip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rocket-chip) RISC V SOC, even questions about real-world rockets (embedded software to control model rockets, simulations, animations or computer games depicting real-world rockets).

Given how many things "Rocket" can mean, it is unlikely to be used consistently. The best solution is burninate the [rocket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rocket) tag, and retag its questions to which specific "rocket" they are actually about.

Comment: Blowup [rocket].

Comment: Send [rocket] into space. Time for [rocket] to blast off. So many possibilities.

Comment: Houston, we have a problem with our [rocket]

Comment: Whoever came up with this tag was off their [rocket].

Comment: Let's rapidly disassemble the [rocket]?

Comment: Doing my part by summarily updating any and every vaguely pun-resembling content with tags in it.

Comment: I would imagine stackoverflow has the ability to just mix those tags in together (when searching and the like) so that rkt and rocket reference the same thing.  (and not just have only a percentage show up in results for that tag)

Comment: This [rocket] doesn't work right, it's time for a new one.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

With that few questions that match the tag wiki (it looks like a grand total of 7 out of 27 questions are "correctly" tagged), I don't think there's any value to a merge. The usage isn't remotely consistent, despite the tag wiki, with no consensus.

We should just burn the entire tag, retagging to the unambiguous tags you mentioned, such as:

- [rkt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rkt) for the container runtime
- [rocket-u2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rocket-u2) for Rocket Software products
- [rocket.chat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rocket.chat) for the chat client
- [rocket-chip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rocket-chip) for the RISC-V SoC
- [rust-rocket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rust-rocket) for the Rust web framework

Comment: Also if you agree, consider tagging this question [meta-tag:burninate-request]

Comment: I agree with your point. I have edited the question to change this from a tag merge request into a tag burnination request.

Comment: This seems like something that can be burninated without mod assistance. Currently 21 for, 1 against, so there's consensus. Post been out for a couple of days. So if someone is bored, I'd say go ahead and burn away.

Comment: If you clean the tag up we can just synonym it to [rocket.chat], which is what the excerpt suggests it is supposed to mean anyways

Comment: And [rocket] for real rockets.

Comment: @Machavity don't you mean [rkt] not [rocket.chat], which is what the tag wiki says [rocket] means. But actually I don't support that because [rkt] is discontinued. I think [rocket] should be blacklisted (or whatever word they are calling that now) rather than made a synonym of anything. It has too many disparate meanings, I don't see why one of those should be privileged as being the synonym

Comment: @SimonKissane Because someone will recreate it and blacklisting is much harder. If you want to eliminate bad usage, use a synonym when able. Blacklists are reserved for [stubborn tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/367027/2370483)

Comment: I guess if it has to be a synonym for something, [rocket.chat] would be it, simply because that appears to be more popular than any of the other rockets (if we judge popularity by the number of tagged questions)